# Move a JLabel inside of JPanel without losing hierarchy

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

So I'm moving a `JLabel` inside of `JPanel` and I want the `JPanel` to automatically show scrolls bars that lead you to the `JLabel` wich I moved out of it.

The problem is that when I set the new `JLabel` location and this location is out of the `JPanel`, it loses its hierarchy so the `JLabel` stops being part of the `JPanel` and as a result the panel doesn't scrolls and you can't see the `JLabel`. So this is my code if you can tell how can I do this. Thanks.

```
//Panel creation
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setSize(500, 500);
panel.setAutoscrolls(true);

//Label creation
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setText("Hi");
label.setSize(40, 40);

//Adding Jlabel to Panel
panel.add(label);

label.setLocation(800, 200);//this invalidates inherancy
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a hierarchy problem. If you debug you might notice that it retains the parent. The problem is that it is out side of the canvas, so it never gets painted. What are you trying to do? Why are you moving the `JLabel` so far? Why can't the `JPanel` be larger, or grow in size dynamically?

Comment: The problem is that I don't want the JPanel to grow, that's why there's a property called "autoscroll". I have to put JLabels in many positions on the screen many of them will be out the screen resolution but I still want to be able to see them by using scroll bars, do you understand what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Don't worry about the `JPanel` growing if It is encapsulated in a `JScrollPane`. It will only grow in your screen if you increase the size of the scroll pane.

Comment: ok I get that, but why the autoscrolls property isn't working, I did the same thing in C# and it was really easy. OK, I realize that the component always grow but why I need to change the Jpanel size when it should do it automatically by setting to true the autoscrolls property.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the functionality of `setAutoscrolls()`. Refer to the javadoc: [JComponent Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setAutoscrolls(boolean))

Comment: Yea you're right about the autoscrolls property but still the Jpanel should have a function to do that. Thanks for the tip I'm gonna do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do it encapsulate the `JPanel` inside a `JScrollPane` and increase its size with `setPreferredSize()`

**Note that using `setSize()` `setWidth()` or `setHeight()` will be ignored by the scroll pane**

A example code of how to set it up follows:

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public TestFrame() {
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(500, 500);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
        scroll.setViewportView(panel);

        add(scroll);

        scroll.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 200);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestFrame frame = new TestFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

In this example, the `JScrollPane` is fixed with 200x200 size, while the `JPanel` inside it has a size of 800x800. You can change this value dynamically as you move your `JLabel` around.

Also, I'd like to mention that null layouts is not the correct approach. In this example, I wanted to minimize the influence of `LayoutManager`s and underlying calls to `setBounds()` by them to emphasize the point I'm trying to get across, which is a pure change of size inside a `JScrollPane`. The whole `JFrame` is just a "vessel" for the example.

Comment: never to suggest to use NullLayout, Swing is designated to use LayoutManagers, as aside JPanel has FlowLayout (as default LayoutManager implemented n API) that accepts only PreferredSize

Comment: @mKorbel I agree. And thank you for adding that, I should put it in the answer as well. I wanted to give an example where there would be no `setBounds()` operations performed by `LayoutManagers` to prove my point about sizing and placing of `JComponents`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was really helpful